# post to facebook from dialog after facebook oauth response not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to post a link in users Facebook timeline using the facebook.ui method to feed the post to Facebook.
For this user is first needed to login to Facebok using the oauth so I can get their email.
But the Facebook ui `FB.ui(obj,callback);` doesn't respond on the on `FB.login(response,scope);`
my example code is:

```
   FB.init({appid, . . });
    FB.login(function(response){
 if(response.authResponse){ ..(get email code here) 
FB.ui(obj, function callback(response) { 
// this is not creating any dialog and not showing any error in the console
                // am i missing something here? 
            });
 },scope:'scope i need'});
```

Comment: Showing the real code would make it easier to answer.

Comment: in FB.ui feed if i give the option display:popup the code dosent work and dosen't show up but if i remove it, the above code works. 
i need it to be shown in popup